# Finding the limit of $\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}$ without using Stirling’s approximatation

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I have proven that the sequence is convergent.

Let $x_n=\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!}$

$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ $=\frac{2n+2}{2n+3}<1$ Therefore the sequence decreases. On the other hand
$x_n>0$. Therefore the sequence is bounded below.
Since we have a sequence that is bounded below and decreases the sequence must converge.

But from here I don’t know how to find the limit. Could you please help me? And could you please say if what I’ve done is necessary or not?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The purported duplicate doesn't answer this question.  One of those answers doesn't provide the limit.  The other answer is actually incorrect.  That OP makes an error in his calculations and the second answer works off that error.

Comment: To get multicharacter subscripts in MathJax, enclose them in braces, so x_{n+1} gives $x_{n+1}$

Comment: Your expression for $x_{n+1}/x_n$ is not correct.  It is $\frac{2n+2}{2n+3}$, which is less than $1$ as you say, leading to the proof of convergence.  If you are going to use slash fractions you need some parentheses.

Comment: I mean a sequence that is bounded from below by zero and decreases seems to be going to $0$ right?  There's a convergence theorem about decreasing/increasing sequences and the supremum/infimum. In this case I suppose $0$ is the infimum of the sequence. Like my name suggests I am not an analysis pro, but I suppose this could be another approach?

Comment: @Algebrageek, a decreasing sequence, bounded below, doesn't have to tend to $0$. I'm sure you can think of a counterexample by yourself if you try.

Comment: In that case the bound $0$ was not a strict enough bound though. If $0$ is the infimum and the sequence is decreasing monotonically the limit must be $0$.This result is monotone convergence. So If one  could prove that $0$ is the infimum, one is also done. I do not suggest this comes for free. You have a lower bound, now one needs to prove this is the greatest lower bound.

Comment: @RossMillikan thanks a lot for teaching me the {} thing)) I'm horrible at MathJax

Comment: It works everywhere.  Putting things in braces groups them.  A good way to learn MathJax is to right click on something you want to know how it was done and pick Show Math As -> TeX Commands.  I learned a lot that way.  It also lets you copy expressions from questions into answers, so if I am evaluating an integral I don't have to retype it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See that

$$x_n = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k}{2k+1}, $$

so that

$$\ln x_n  = \sum_{k=1}^n \ln \left(\frac{2k}{2k+1}\right). $$

So we work with this series.  First argue that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \ln\left(\frac{2k}{2k+1}\right) - \int_{t=1}^{\infty} \ln\left(\frac{2t}{2t+1}\right) \; dt$$

finite.  (If you graph the summmand and the integrand, they differ by a set of little (near) triangles.  Because the functions are monotonic, the triangles can be pushed together and fit in a small rectangle.)

Integration by parts gives

$$ = \int \ln(2t) - \ln(2t+1) \; dt =  t \ln(2t) -\frac{1}{2}\ln(2t+1)(2t+2) + 1/2.$$

And when you evaluate the improper integral you get $-\infty.$   So the limit of the sequence is $e^{-\infty} = 0.$

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering to my question. Honestly we haven't studied integrals or series in class yet so I don't really understand this, but is there maybe an easier way to showing this. If not maybe I picked the wrong exercise to work on and it's my fault.

Answer (score 2):

Observe that, for any $ n\in\mathbb{N} $ : $$\frac{\left(2n\right)!!}{\left(2n+1\right)!!}=\int_{0}^{1}{\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n}\,\mathrm{d}x} $$

Since : \begin{aligned} \int_{0}^{1}{\left(1-x^{2}\right)^{n}\,\mathrm{d}x}&=\int_{0}^{1}{\left(1+x\right)^{n}\left(1-x\right)^{n}\,\mathrm{d}x}\\&\leq\int_{0}^{1}{\left(1+x\right)^{n}\,\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{n+1}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0\end{aligned}

Then : $$ \frac{\left(2n\right)!!}{\left(2n+1\right)!!}\underset{n\to +\infty}{\longrightarrow}0 $$

Answer (score 0):

Similar to another answer, you have that $$x_n = \prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k}{2k+1}$$

Then
$$\ln(x_n) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln\left( \frac{2k}{2k+1} \right)$$

Each term will be negative and with the comparison test, you have that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\ln\left( \frac{2k}{2k+1} \right) < -\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{2k+1} \to -\infty$$

Then $\ln(x_n)$ must go to $-\infty$ as well, and $x_n = \exp(\ln(x_n)) \to 0$.